# Creating shortcuts in Android via ADB

Tags: android, adb

It is possible to create a shortcut from ADB on the launcher of my android? 
I have a .bat file to install my applications from my PC (through double click), but after this I need always to search on the huge (not so user friendly) applications list of the launcher. If it was possible to add this feature to my .bat file would be great.
I already try to search on the web without any luck :S.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's the relatively well-documented `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`, that you could call through `adb shell broadcast`, but one of the extras is the launch-intent. If you can't place that on the command-line, you could write a stub-app that does nothing but broadcast that intent, and then install it, invoke it, and uninstall it from command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to handle this. If your main need is to be able to start your application quickly each time you do a re-edit, then an `adb shell am intent -n com.example.app/.App` is the easiest solution.

If you want to just make a shortcut (and you don't care where) use `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` as everyone says. You'll need an app or bin to do that as the am broadcast won't take nested intents.

If you are working with a specific launcher (like ADW Launcher) you can hack the database of shortcuts. This will allow you to specify the coordinates of the shortcut ([2, 3] in this case)

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/org.adw.launcher/databases/launcher.db "DELETE FROM favorites WHERE _id=1; INSERT INTO favorites VALUES(1,'MyApp','#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.example.app/.App;end',-100,0,2,3,1,1,0,-1,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);"
```

You'll need to tell the launcher to refresh from the database. Usually the only way is to kill the launcher. Later versions of am (the ActivityManager shell command) have options for restarting a package, earlier versions don't. In that case you'd need to write a small app:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.restartPackage("org.adw.launcher");
```

Comment: what if i want to create the shortcut by code, to a specific lanuncher app and a specific activity within it?

Comment: All of the above code does refer to a specific activity within a specific app. I only have experience with ADW, other launchers must store the info somewhere, undoubtedly a database.

Comment: Yes, I've made a post about it. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394477/how-to-create-a-shortcut-of-an-app-on-a-specific-launcher-app . one of the comments there is the answer.