# How to create a shortcut of an app on a SPECIFIC launcher app?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, android-launcher, shortcut-file

### Background

I already know how to put a shortcut to an app globally:

Intent shortcutIntent=new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,fullPathToActivity));

```
final Intent putShortCutIntent=new Intent();
putShortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,shortcutIntent);
//... <=preparing putShortcutIntent with some customizations (title, icon,...)
putShortcutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(putShortcutIntent);
```

This works well.
What I do wish to do is to be able to put the shortcut only to a specific launcher app (in fact it's the default launcher app, but that's not the problem).

### The problem

For some reason, instead of putting the shortcut on the launcher app i've chosen (in this case "nova launcher") , I end up getting the shortcut created on the touchwiz launcher alone.

### What I've tried

the obvious solutions were:

```
putShortcutIntent.setClassName(launcherPackageName,broadcastReceiverClassName);
```

or

```
putShortcutIntent.setPackage(launcherPackageName);
```

none worked, even though i've seen the values fine during debug mode (the parameters were legit).

The weird thing is that if I use this, it puts the shortcut only on the touchwiz launcher...

### The question

Why does it occur?

How come I can't choose where to send the broadcast to?

is there a better way to achieve this?

---

EDIT: here's how I get the default broadcastReceiver that can handle the shortcut creation intent:

```
final ResolveInfo defaultActivityForLauncherIntent=... //here i return the correct app that is the default launcher
Intent intentForAddingShortcutOnDesktop=new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
//<= here I prepare the intent of creating a shortcut
final List<ResolveInfo> broadcastReceiversResolveInfos=context.getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intentForAddingShortcutOnDesktop,0);
for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo : broadcastReceiversResolveInfos)
  if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals(defaultActivityForLauncherIntent.activityInfo.packageName))
    {
    intentForAddingShortcutOnDesktop.setComponent(new ComponentName(//
        resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
    break;
    }
context.sendBroadcast(intentForAddingShortcutOnDesktop);
```

it seems part of the confusion was that the play store was set to create new shortcuts.

This, and the fact i forgot to query the broadcastReceivers instead of activities...

Comment: "Why does it occur?" -- do you have any evidence that Nova Launcher pays attention to this broadcast? There's no rule that requires them to do so.

Comment: what do you mean? when the intent is global, it creates the shortcut just fine. do you really think that they've added a condition that if it's not global (even if it's meant for nova launcher), ignore the intent?

Comment: @CommonsWare the intent documentation says that the component must override the way activites are being resolved: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html . read the part about the component

Comment: "what do you mean?" -- I mean that Nova Launcher is a program, written by programmers. "do you really think that they've added a condition that if it's not global (even if it's meant for nova launcher), ignore the intent?" -- I certainly cannot rule it out. Or, perhaps you have the wrong component. After all, a launcher is an *activity*, and you are putting that component in a *broadcast* `Intent` (`putShortcutIntent`), according to your "What I've tried" section. By definition, that cannot work.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, so what can I do in order to send the intent only to a specific app?

Comment: Well, ideally, you wouldn't. That being said, you need to find the `BroadcastReceiver` of that app that handles `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` (if any), and use that as your `ComponentName` with the broadcast `Intent`. You can try to use `PackageManager` to determine this dynamically, rather than hardcoding some value, which might differ based on app versions.

Comment: Why shouldn't I? I wish to allow the user to choose this, so that only the launcher of his choice would get new shortcuts (i'm making a tool that does many things with apps). anyway, it now works, and i've found out one thing that have confused me is that the play store itself was also creating shortcuts (via the settings). i wonder though how this can be done on dynamically registered broadcastReceivers. do you know the answer to this? btw, you can put the answer instead of using the comments. that way i can tick it as the correct answer.